# Word request: "the idea * into my dreams*

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> I was thinking about it so much it even [**got into**] my dreams

Is there a verb I could use here to express some idea spread all over my mind it *penetrated* (?) my dreams (subconsciousness)? The synonym in my mothertongue translates to something like "pervade" or "infiltrate" through a barrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your suggestions are already very good

> ✔️**Yes:**   it **got into** my dreams

Is perfectly clear and works well in conversational English.

Your other suggestions,

> ✔️**Yes:**
>
> - penetrated my dreams, penetrated my subconscious, pervaded or infiltrated my dreams

are perfect, and so is “it **invaded** my dreams”.

Answer (score 0):

The question is  **"the idea * into my dreams***

In English the act of something/body entering into your dreams indicates that you are in an extreme state of Bliss/anxiety/etc.

Examples

I dreamed about her again, I just cannot get her out of my head.

I cannot stop thinking about this new installation, I even dreamed about work last night.

So it is a little **different from your mother language**. I think filtered is the action you suggest but it does not sound so good in this context. However,  I could suggest **percolate or percolated** this may give the impression of something bubbling through your mind and entering your dreams. As I do not know the context you wish to use, it could be that something more harsh like **Encroached on** or even **Violated** maybe suitable. Of course, the good old fashioned "**entered**" could still be the best choice!

**I was thinking about it so much it even entered into my dreams**

Comment: Thank you for this general perspective, that's exactly what I was looking for. But what would be the correct form? The idea "percolated into" my dreams? Or just "percolated"?

Comment: @Probably "percolated into". I was thinking about it so much it even entered into my dreams is a common phrase so using this as a reference, just replace entered into with percolated into.